# Cant understand why ${NSD_GetState} $Checkbox is not working

Tags: installation, nsis

Can anyone explain to me, why ${NSD_GetState} $Checkbox is not working ?
I lost about 4 hours trying to find out what is wrong. I tried diffrent variants but in THIS script they are not working.

Actualy it is my first attempt to make a nsis installer, so I even dont know where should I look for mistake or I just dont understand the logic of this language.

From Russia with love :)
And sorry for my bad english

```
!define NAME "Simple LiveUSB installer"
!define FILENAME "USB"
!define VERSION "v0.1"

Name "${NAME} ${VERSION}"
OutFile "${FILENAME}.exe"

SetCompressor LZMA
ShowInstDetails hide
XPStyle on

!include MUI2.nsh
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
;!include LogicLib.nsh

!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\HEADER2.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH
!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\media-floppy.ico"


Page custom drivePage
Page custom Var123

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "Russian"
LangString DrivePage_Title ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "TEXT"
LangString DrivePage_Title2 ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "TEXT"
LangString DrivePage_Text ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "TEXT"
LangString DrivePage_Text2 ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "Format"
LangString DrivePage_Input ${LANG_RUSSIAN} "Choose"



Var Label
Var Label2
Var Checkbox
;Var Checkbox_State
Var DestDriveHW
Var DestDrive

# Functions #######################################

Function drivePage

    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(DrivePage_Title) $(DrivePage_Title2)

    nsDialogs::Create 1018

    ${If} $DestDrive == ""
        GetDlgItem $6 $HWNDPARENT 1
        EnableWindow $6 0
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 160 $(DrivePage_Text)
    Pop $Label

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10 182 100% 15 $(DrivePage_Input)
    Pop $Label2

    ${NSD_CreateDroplist} 10 200 13% 20 ""
    Pop $DestDriveHw

    ${NSD_OnChange} $DestDriveHw db_select.onchange
    ${GetDrives} "FDD" driveListFiller

    ${If} $DestDrive != ""
        ${NSD_CB_SelectString} $DestDriveHw $DestDrive
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 80 203 100% 10u $(DrivePage_Text2)
    Pop $Checkbox

    ${If} $Checkbox_State == ${BST_CHECKED}
        ${NSD_Check} $Checkbox_State
    ${EndIf}

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd


Function db_select.onchange
    Pop $DestDriveHw

    ${NSD_GetText} $DestDriveHw $0
    StrCpy $DestDrive "$0"
    GetDlgItem $6 $HWNDPARENT 1
    EnableWindow $6 1
FunctionEnd

Function driveListFiller
    SendMessage $DestDriveHw ${CB_ADDSTRING} 0 "STR:$9"
    Push 1
FunctionEnd

Function Var123
Pop $Checkbox
MessageBox mb_ok "FIN Checkbox_State=$Checkbox_State Checkbox=$Checkbox"
${NSD_GetState} $Checkbox $0
${If} $0 <> 0
    MessageBox mb_ok "Custom checkbox was checked... N=$0"
${EndIf}
${If} $0 == 0
    MessageBox mb_ok "Custom checkbox ZERO... N=$0"
${EndIf}

Functionend

# Section #######################################

Section "" main


InitPluginsDir

File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\syslinux.cfg  "${NSISDIR}\plugins\syslinux.cfg"
File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\syslinux.exe  "${NSISDIR}\plugins\syslinux.exe"

File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\nsExec.dll  "${NSISDIR}\plugins\nsExec.dll"


StrCpy $R0 $DestDrive -1


;ExpandEnvStrings $0 %COMSPEC%
;nsExec::Exec '"$0" /c echo. | format $R0 /q /x /v:LiveUSB /fs:fat32'



nsExec::Exec '$PLUGINSDIR\syslinux.exe -maf -d boot\syslinux $R0' 


;SendMessage $Checkbox ${BM_GETSTATE} 0 0 $0
;${If} $0 != 0

;  MessageBox MB_OK checked!

;${EndIf}

;Pop $Checkbox
;MessageBox mb_ok "FIN Checkbox_State=$Checkbox_State Checkbox=$Checkbox"
;${NSD_GetState} $Checkbox $0
;${If} $0 <> 0
;    MessageBox mb_ok "Custom checkbox was checked... N=$0"
;${EndIf}


CopyFiles $PLUGINSDIR\syslinux.cfg  "$R0\syslinux.cfg"


SectionEnd
```

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much unrelated code in your example that it is a bit hard to understand what you really want to do.

If you want to retrieve the state of a checkbox on another page then you must save the state because the checkbox control is destroyed when you leave the page.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var hwndCheckbox
Var CheckboxState
Page Custom myPageWithCombobox myPageWithComboboxLeaveCallback
Page Custom myPageWithComboState



Function .onInit
StrCpy $CheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED} ; Set the initial state. This is optional but useful if you use $CheckboxState in a section when the installer is silent
FunctionEnd

Function myPageWithCombobox
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 80 203 100% 10u $(DrivePage_Text2)
Pop $hwndCheckbox
${NSD_SetState} $hwndCheckbox $CheckboxState ; Reuse the existing state so it is correct when the back button is used

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function myPageWithComboboxLeaveCallback
${NSD_GetState} $hwndCheckbox $CheckboxState ; Save the state so we can retrieve it on the next page
FunctionEnd



Function myPageWithComboState
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 160 CheckboxState=$CheckboxState
Pop $0

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```