# Files for both applications are installed in both destination folders

Tags: nsis

Please note that I initially created an installer for two applications based on https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Two_installations_in_one_installer where the first application is the main one while the second application is the license manager. That said, I did remove the nested checkboxes with only one layer of checkboxes. FYI, I have also been referencing this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24187/Creating-an-Installer?msg=5782957#xx5782957xx

The issue that I am having is that when I run the installer, all of the files from `MyApp` and `FlexLM` are installed in the `$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}` folder and in the `C:\${FLEX_DIR}`.  So when I am installing two applications, it looks like both `SEC1` and `SEC3` are executed for the MyApp installation and both SEC1 and SEC3 are executed for the `FlexLM` installation:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"
    
;Include Modern UI
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MAJOR_VERSION "1" 
!define MINOR_VERSION "2" 
!define PATCH_VERSION "3" 
!define BUILD_VERSION "4" 
    
!define APP_COPYRIGHT "MyApp © MyCompany 2021"
!define COMPANY_NAME "MyCompany"
!define FLEX_LM "FlexLM"        
!define FLEX_DIR "FlexSQI"            
!define LANG_ENGLSH "English" 
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}.${BUILD_VERSION}"
!define SETUP_NAME "MyAppSetup.exe"

BrandingText "MyCompany"

OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\$PRODUCT_NAME" ""
ShowInstDetails hide
ShowUnInstDetails hide

SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
SetCompressorDictSize 12

Var MyAppCheckboxState
Var FlexLmCheckboxState

;Request application privileges for Windows 
RequestExecutionLevel admin

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "MyAppLicense.txt"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesCheck
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ComponentsLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS   
 
## This is the title on the MyApp Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A)"
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 
## This is the title on the FlexLM Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B)"
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DeleteSectionsINI
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Languages

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------

LangString NoSectionsSelected ${LANG_ENGLSH} "You haven't selected any sections!"

LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${PRODUCT_NAME} in the following folder..."
LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${FLEX_LM} in the following folder..."

;--------------------------------
; Settings
 
!define PROG1_InstDir    "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PROG1_StartIndex ${SEC1}
!define PROG1_EndIndex   ${SEC1}
 
!define PROG2_InstDir "C:\${FLEX_DIR}"
!define PROG2_StartIndex ${SEC3}
!define PROG2_EndIndex   ${SEC3}

;--------------------------------
; Start sections

Section "MyApp" SEC1
  StrCpy $MyAppCheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED}
  ${If} $MyAppCheckboxState == ${BST_CHECKED}
    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    # specify files to go in output path
    File config.dat 
    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Version' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{0be21143-9089-47fa-9736-c45609d13d70}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{0be21143-9089-47fa-9736-c45609d13d70}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                      
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\""

    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe        

  ${EndIf}

  # messagebox mb_ok sec1
SectionEnd

Section "FlexLM" SEC3
  StrCpy $FlexLmCheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED}
  ${If} $FlexLmCheckboxState == ${BST_CHECKED}    
    ##All the files in Group 2 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    File installs.exe
    File lmdown.exe
    File lmflex.exe
    
    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe

  ${EndIf}    

  # messagebox mb_ok sec3
 
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;Language strings
  LangString DESC_SecMyApp ${LANG_ENGLISH} "MyAppTM software is an easy-to-use suite of tools."
  LangString DESC_SecFlexLM ${LANG_ENGLISH} "FlexSQI contains all the files necessary to implement the FlexLM license server."

  ;Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN    
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC1} $(DESC_SecMyApp)
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC3} $(DESC_SecFlexLM)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

Section "Uninstall"  

  # Always delete uninstaller first
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
 
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for MyApp
  Delete $INSTDIR\config.dat
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyAppLicense.txt
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Modern UI Test"       
        
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for FlexLM
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmdown.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmflex.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\installs.exe

  # Delete the MyApp and FlexLM directories
  RMDir $INSTDIR

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
; Please don`t modify below here unless you`re a NSIS 'wiz-kid'
 
## Create $PLUGINSDIR
Function .onInit
  InitPluginsDir

  SetOutPath $TEMP
  File /oname=spltmp.bmp "MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp"

  splash::show 2000 $TEMP\spltmp

  Pop $0 ; $0 has '1' if the user closed the splash screen early,
  ; '0' if everything closed normally, and '-1' if some error occurred.

  Delete $TEMP\spltmp.bmp  
FunctionEnd
        
## If user goes back to this page from 1st Directory page
## we need to put the sections back to how they were before
Var IfBack
Function SelectFilesCheck
  StrCmp $IfBack 1 0 NoCheck
  ;Call ResetFiles
  NoCheck:
FunctionEnd
 
## Also if no sections are selected, warn the user!
Function ComponentsLeave
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 Call IsPROG1Selected
  Pop $R0
 Call IsPROG2Selected
  Pop $R1
 StrCmp $R0 1 End
 StrCmp $R1 1 End
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "$(NoSectionsSelected)"
 Abort
 
End:
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
    
Function IsPROG1Selected
Push $R0

 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex} # Group 1 start
 
   SectionGetFlags 0 $R0            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R0 1
 
Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
 
Function IsPROG2Selected
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R1 ${PROG2_StartIndex}    # Group 2 start
 
   IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1
   SectionGetFlags 1 $R1            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R1 $R1 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R1 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R1 1
 
Exch $R1
FunctionEnd

## Here we are selecting first sections to install
## by unselecting all the others!
Function SelectFilesA
 
 # If user clicks Back now, we will know to reselect Group 2`s sections for
 # Components page
 StrCpy $IfBack 1
 
 # We need to save the state of the Group 2 Sections
 # for the next InstFiles page
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG2_StartIndex} # Group 2 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;   SectionGetFlags $R0 $R1                 # Get section flags
;    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\sections.ini" Sections $R0 $R1 # Save state
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0               # Then unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG2_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
 # Don`t install prog 1?
 Call IsPROG1Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG1_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG1_InstDir}"
 
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
 
## Here we need to unselect all Group 1 sections
## and then re-select those in Group 2 (that the user had selected on
## Components page)
Function SelectFilesB
Push $R0
;Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex}    # Group 1 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0       # Unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG1_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
; Call ResetFiles
 
 # Don't install prog 2?
 Call IsPROG2Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG2_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG2_InstDir}"
 
;Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
## Here we are deleting the temp INI file at the end of installation
Function DeleteSectionsINI
 FlushINI "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
 Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
FunctionEnd
```

How can I get only the MyApp files to be installed in $PROGRAMFILES64${PRODUCT_NAME} (i.e., the files from SEC1), and only the Files from FlexLM to be installed in C:\FlexLM?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Please find my updated code here:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"
    
;Include Modern UI
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MAJOR_VERSION "1" 
!define MINOR_VERSION "2" 
!define PATCH_VERSION "3" 
!define BUILD_VERSION "4" 
    
!define APP_COPYRIGHT "MyApp © MyCompany 2021"
!define COMPANY_NAME "MyCompany"
!define FLEX_LM "FlexLM"        
!define FLEX_DIR "FlexSQI"            
!define LANG_ENGLSH "English" 
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}.${BUILD_VERSION}"
!define SETUP_NAME "MyAppSetup.exe"

BrandingText "MyCompany"

OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\$PRODUCT_NAME" ""
ShowInstDetails hide
ShowUnInstDetails hide

SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
SetCompressorDictSize 12

Var MyAppCheckboxState
Var FlexLmCheckboxState
Var MyAppInstallDir
Var FlexLmInstallDir

;Request application privileges for Windows 
RequestExecutionLevel admin

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "MyAppLicense.txt"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesCheck
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ComponentsLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS   
 
## This is the title on the MyApp Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A)"
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 
## This is the title on the FlexLM Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B)"
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DeleteSectionsINI
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Languages

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------

LangString NoSectionsSelected ${LANG_ENGLSH} "You haven't selected any sections!"

LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${PRODUCT_NAME} in the following folder..."
LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${FLEX_LM} in the following folder..."

;--------------------------------
; Settings
 
!define PROG1_InstDir    "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
!define PROG1_StartIndex ${SEC1}
!define PROG1_EndIndex   ${SEC1}
 
!define PROG2_InstDir "C:\${FLEX_DIR}"
!define PROG2_StartIndex ${SEC3}
!define PROG2_EndIndex   ${SEC3}

;--------------------------------
; Function
; StrContains
; This function does a case sensitive searches for an occurrence of a substring in a string. 
; It returns the substring if it is found. 
; Otherwise it returns null(""). 
; Written by kenglish_hi
; Adapted from StrReplace written by dandaman32
 
 
Var STR_HAYSTACK
Var STR_NEEDLE
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4
Var STR_RETURN_VAR
 
Function StrContains
  Exch $STR_NEEDLE
  Exch 1
  Exch $STR_HAYSTACK
  ; Uncomment to debug
  ;MessageBox MB_OK 'STR_NEEDLE = $STR_NEEDLE STR_HAYSTACK = $STR_HAYSTACK '
    StrCpy $STR_RETURN_VAR ""
    StrCpy $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 -1
    StrLen $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2 $STR_NEEDLE
    StrLen $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4 $STR_HAYSTACK
    loop:
      IntOp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 + 1
      StrCpy $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3 $STR_HAYSTACK $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1
      StrCmp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3 $STR_NEEDLE found
      StrCmp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4 done
      Goto loop
    found:
      StrCpy $STR_RETURN_VAR $STR_NEEDLE
      Goto done
    done:
   Pop $STR_NEEDLE ;Prevent "invalid opcode" errors and keep the
   Exch $STR_RETURN_VAR  
FunctionEnd
 
!macro _StrContainsConstructor OUT NEEDLE HAYSTACK
  Push `${HAYSTACK}`
  Push `${NEEDLE}`
  Call StrContains
  Pop `${OUT}`
!macroend
 
!define StrContains '!insertmacro "_StrContainsConstructor"'

;--------------------------------
; Start sections

Section "MyApp" SEC1
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC1}
    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "MyQpp" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $MyAppInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'
    doneMyApp:  

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'    

    # specify files to go in output path
    File config.dat 
    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$InstDir\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Version' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{A0E84732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-462B8DF92DCD}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{A0E84732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-462B8DF92DCD}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                      
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\""

    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe        
    doneFlex:   
  ${EndIf}

  # messagebox mb_ok sec1
SectionEnd

Section "FlexLM" SEC3
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC3}
    ##All the files in Group 2 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC3 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"

    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "Pro" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $MyAppInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'
    doneFlex:     

    File installs.exe
    File lmdown.exe
    File lmflex.exe
    
    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
    doneQI: 
  ${EndIf}    

  # messagebox mb_ok sec3
 
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;Language strings
  LangString DESC_SecMyApp ${LANG_ENGLISH} "MyAppTM software is an easy-to-use suite of tools."
  LangString DESC_SecFlexLM ${LANG_ENGLISH} "FlexSQI contains all the files necessary to implement the FlexLM license server."

  ;Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN    
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC1} $(DESC_SecMyApp)
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC3} $(DESC_SecFlexLM)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

Section "Uninstall"  

  # Always delete uninstaller first
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
 
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for MyApp
  Delete $INSTDIR\config.dat
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyAppLicense.txt
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Modern UI Test"     
        
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for FlexLM
  Delete $INSTDIR\installs.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmborrow.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmflex.exe

  # Delete the MyApp and FlexLM directories
  RMDir $INSTDIR

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
; Please don`t modify below here unless you`re a NSIS 'wiz-kid'
 
## Create $PLUGINSDIR
Function .onInit
  InitPluginsDir

  SetOutPath $TEMP
  File /oname=spltmp.bmp "MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp"

  splash::show 2000 $TEMP\spltmp

  Pop $0 ; $0 has '1' if the user closed the splash screen early,
  ; '0' if everything closed normally, and '-1' if some error occurred.

  Delete $TEMP\spltmp.bmp  
FunctionEnd
        
## If user goes back to this page from 1st Directory page
## we need to put the sections back to how they were before
Var IfBack
Function SelectFilesCheck
  StrCmp $IfBack 1 0 NoCheck
  ;Call ResetFiles
  NoCheck:
FunctionEnd
 
## Also if no sections are selected, warn the user!
Function ComponentsLeave
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 Call IsPROG1Selected
  Pop $R0
 Call IsPROG2Selected
  Pop $R1
 StrCmp $R0 1 End
 StrCmp $R1 1 End
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "$(NoSectionsSelected)"
 Abort
 
End:
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
    
Function IsPROG1Selected
Push $R0

 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex} # Group 1 start
 
   SectionGetFlags 0 $R0            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R0 1
 
Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
 
Function IsPROG2Selected
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R1 ${PROG2_StartIndex}    # Group 2 start
 
   IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1
   SectionGetFlags 1 $R1            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R1 $R1 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R1 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R1 1
 
Exch $R1
FunctionEnd

## Here we are selecting first sections to install
## by unselecting all the others!
Function SelectFilesA
 
 # If user clicks Back now, we will know to reselect Group 2`s sections for
 # Components page
 StrCpy $IfBack 1
 
 # We need to save the state of the Group 2 Sections
 # for the next InstFiles page
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG2_StartIndex} # Group 2 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;   SectionGetFlags $R0 $R1                 # Get section flags
;    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\sections.ini" Sections $R0 $R1 # Save state
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0               # Then unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG2_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
 # Don`t install prog 1?
 Call IsPROG1Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG1_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG1_InstDir}"
 
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
 
## Here we need to unselect all Group 1 sections
## and then re-select those in Group 2 (that the user had selected on
## Components page)
Function SelectFilesB
Push $R0
;Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex}    # Group 1 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0       # Unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG1_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
; Call ResetFiles
 
 # Don't install prog 2?
 Call IsPROG2Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG2_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG2_InstDir}"
 
;Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
## Here we are deleting the temp INI file at the end of installation
Function DeleteSectionsINI
 FlushINI "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
 Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
 
  # FlexLM libs 
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "DeleteSectionsINI #1 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
  Delete $MyAppInstallDir\installs.exe
  Delete $MyAppInstallDir\lmborrow.exe
  
  # QI Pro files 
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "DeleteSectionsINI #1 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\config.dat
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\MyApp.exe
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\MyAppLicense.txt
   
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: The other day I recommended that you don't use multiple InstFiles page and now here we are 

Comment: Okay maybe installing two applications in a single installer script is not a best practice, but that said, there is an example of a script that installs two applications in a single installer script right on the NSIS website, so shouldn't that mean this is actually supported by Nullsoft?  See https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Two_installations_in_one_installer

Comment: It's a Wiki, anyone can edit. Multiple InstFiles pages can be made to work just because that scenario is not specifically blocked but it does require you to manually handle sections. I'd say the best way to debug this is to add a components page before each InstFiles page and figure out why sections are not in their correct state.

Comment: I still don't understand why you insist on having two InstFiles pages. Having two directory pages and just a single InstFiles page is so much easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the code from the Wiki and it works perfectly. You commented out the loop in `SelectFilesA`/`B` so no wonder the section logic is broken in your example.

You also have some other issues:

```
StrCpy $MyAppCheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED}
${If} $MyAppCheckboxState == ${BST_CHECKED}
```

This makes no sense, this will always be true!

Also, `CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"` is wrong, it should be `CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$InstDir\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"`.

Comment: The reason I commented out the loop is because originally the checkboxes were nested in 2 levels but I just want a single checkbox level.  Thx for pointing out that issue about ${BST_CHECKED}.  How do I then get the value of whether the checkbox is checked or not?  Sorry I am new at this NSIS scripting

Comment: When I look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174211/cant-understand-why-nsd-getstate-checkbox-is-not-working I see that you can get a checkbox state using ${NSD_GetState} but I don't know the name/handle of the checkboxes in MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS whereas in the SO link the checkbox is called $hwndCheckbox because it was explicitly created.

Comment: The component page does not use checkboxes, it is a treeview but you can use `${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC1}` to check at any time. If you just want a single level, remove the SectionGroups.

Comment: Thanks.  What if I decide to unselect "MyApp"?  Then if I use the `${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC1}` it will still result in the directory selection dialog being displayed and the MyApp directory being created, though it will be empty.  How can I make it so that this directory select dialog does not even show up?

Comment: In the MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE callback function for the first directory page, if `Abort` is called, the page is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2:

Here is my final solution--many thanks to [@Anders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501/anders).  It may not be the most ideal or elegant solution, but it works for what I need.  I tried to add this to my question but for some reason SO won't let me.

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"
    
;Include Modern UI
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MAJOR_VERSION "1" 
!define MINOR_VERSION "2" 
!define PATCH_VERSION "3" 
!define BUILD_VERSION "4" 
    
!define APP_COPYRIGHT "MyApp © MyCompany 2021"
!define COMPANY_NAME "MyCompany"
!define FLEX_LM "FlexLM"        
!define FLEX_DIR "FlexSQI"            
!define LANG_ENGLSH "English" 
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyApp"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "${MAJOR_VERSION}.${MINOR_VERSION}.${PATCH_VERSION}.${BUILD_VERSION}"
!define SETUP_NAME "MyAppSetup.exe"

BrandingText "MyCompany"

OutFile ${SETUP_NAME}
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME}"

InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\$PRODUCT_NAME" ""
ShowInstDetails hide
ShowUnInstDetails hide

SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
SetCompressorDictSize 12

Var MyAppInstallDir
Var FlexLmInstallDir

;Request application privileges for Windows 
RequestExecutionLevel admin

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "MyAppLicense.txt"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesCheck
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ComponentsLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS   
 
## This is the title on the MyApp Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A)"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Please choose the folder in which to install MyApp."
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesA
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
 
## This is the title on the FlexLM Directory page
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "$(MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B)"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Please choose the folder in which to install FlexLM."
 
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE SelectFilesB
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE DeleteSectionsINI
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Languages

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------

LangString NoSectionsSelected ${LANG_ENGLSH} "You haven't selected any sections!"

LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_A ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${PRODUCT_NAME} in the following folder..."
LangString MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP_B ${LANG_ENGLSH} "Setup will install \
${FLEX_LM} in the following folder..."

;--------------------------------
; Settings
 
!define PROG1_InstDir    "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\"
!define PROG1_StartIndex ${SEC1}
!define PROG1_EndIndex   ${SEC1}
 
!define PROG2_InstDir "C:\${FLEX_DIR}"
!define PROG2_StartIndex ${SEC3}
!define PROG2_EndIndex   ${SEC3}

;--------------------------------
; Function
; StrContains
; This function does a case sensitive searches for an occurrence of a substring in a string. 
; It returns the substring if it is found. 
; Otherwise it returns null(""). 
; Written by kenglish_hi
; Adapted from StrReplace written by dandaman32
 
 
Var STR_HAYSTACK
Var STR_NEEDLE
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3
Var STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4
Var STR_RETURN_VAR
 
Function StrContains
  Exch $STR_NEEDLE
  Exch 1
  Exch $STR_HAYSTACK
  ; Uncomment to debug
  ;MessageBox MB_OK 'STR_NEEDLE = $STR_NEEDLE STR_HAYSTACK = $STR_HAYSTACK '
    StrCpy $STR_RETURN_VAR ""
    StrCpy $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 -1
    StrLen $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2 $STR_NEEDLE
    StrLen $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4 $STR_HAYSTACK
    loop:
      IntOp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 + 1
      StrCpy $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3 $STR_HAYSTACK $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_2 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1
      StrCmp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_3 $STR_NEEDLE found
      StrCmp $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_1 $STR_CONTAINS_VAR_4 done
      Goto loop
    found:
      StrCpy $STR_RETURN_VAR $STR_NEEDLE
      Goto done
    done:
   Pop $STR_NEEDLE ;Prevent "invalid opcode" errors and keep the
   Exch $STR_RETURN_VAR  
FunctionEnd
 
!macro _StrContainsConstructor OUT NEEDLE HAYSTACK
  Push `${HAYSTACK}`
  Push `${NEEDLE}`
  Call StrContains
  Pop `${OUT}`
!macroend
 
!define StrContains '!insertmacro "_StrContainsConstructor"'

;--------------------------------
; Start sections

Section "MyApp" SEC1
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "MyApp" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $MyAppInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'
    doneMyApp:  

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'    

    ##All the files in Group 1 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

    File MyApp.exe
    File ReleaseNotes.txt
    File MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
    File MyAppLicense.txt  
  
    # create a shortcut named "new shortcut" in the start menu programs directory
    CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$InstDir\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe" 

    # Add application to registry  
    ClearErrors
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Company Name' "${COMPANY_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'Version' "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
    WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}" 'AppID' "{A0E84732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-462B8DF92DCD}"
 
    # Add program to Add/Remove programs 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayIcon" "$PROGRAMFILES64\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "AppID" "{A0E84732-E2B2-46E5-8CA2-462B8DF92DCD}"              
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayName" "${PRODUCT_NAME}"
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "InstallLocation" "$INSTDIR"                      
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                   "Publisher" "${COMPANY_NAME}"                 
    WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
                     "UninstallString" "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe$\""

    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe        
    doneFlex:   

  # messagebox mb_ok sec1
SectionEnd

Section "FlexLM" SEC3
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC3 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"

    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
    ${StrContains} $0 "Pro" "$INSTDIR"
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #2 0 is $0"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundMyApp
      StrCpy $MyAppInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
      Goto doneMyApp
    notfoundMyApp:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find MyApp string'

    ${StrContains} $0 "Flex" "$INSTDIR"
    StrCmp $0 "" notfoundFlex
      StrCpy $FlexLmInstallDir "$INSTDIR"
      ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #4 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
      Goto doneFlex
    notfoundFlex:
      ;MessageBox MB_OK 'Did not find Flex string'
    doneFlex:     

    ##All the files in Group 2 will be installed to the same location, $INSTDIR
    SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
    File installs.exe
    File lmdown.exe
    File lmflex.exe
    
    # define uninstaller name
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
    doneQI: 

  # messagebox mb_ok sec3
 
SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Descriptions

  ;Language strings
  LangString DESC_SecMyApp ${LANG_ENGLISH} "MyAppTM software is an easy-to-use suite of tools."
  LangString DESC_SecFlexLM ${LANG_ENGLISH} "FlexSQI contains all the files necessary to implement the FlexLM license server."

  ;Assign language strings to sections
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN    
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC1} $(DESC_SecMyApp)
    !insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC3} $(DESC_SecFlexLM)
  !insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

Section "Uninstall"  

  # Always delete uninstaller first
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe
 
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for MyApp
  Delete $INSTDIR\config.dat
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyApp.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $INSTDIR\MyAppLicense.txt
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk"
  DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  DeleteRegKey /ifempty HKCU "Software\Modern UI Test"     
        
  # now delete installed files and registry keys for FlexLM
  Delete $INSTDIR\installs.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmborrow.exe
  Delete $INSTDIR\lmflex.exe

  # Delete the MyApp and FlexLM directories
  RMDir $INSTDIR

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
; Please don`t modify below here unless you`re a NSIS 'wiz-kid'
 
## Create $PLUGINSDIR
Function .onInit
  InitPluginsDir

  SetOutPath $TEMP
  File /oname=spltmp.bmp "MyCompany_LandingPage_114.bmp"

  splash::show 2000 $TEMP\spltmp

  Pop $0 ; $0 has '1' if the user closed the splash screen early,
  ; '0' if everything closed normally, and '-1' if some error occurred.

  Delete $TEMP\spltmp.bmp  
FunctionEnd
        
## If user goes back to this page from 1st Directory page
## we need to put the sections back to how they were before
Var IfBack
Function SelectFilesCheck
  StrCmp $IfBack 1 0 NoCheck
  ;Call ResetFiles
  NoCheck:
FunctionEnd
 
## Also if no sections are selected, warn the user!
Function ComponentsLeave
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 Call IsPROG1Selected
  Pop $R0
 Call IsPROG2Selected
  Pop $R1
 StrCmp $R0 1 End
 StrCmp $R1 1 End
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
 MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "$(NoSectionsSelected)"
 Abort
 
End:
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
    
Function IsPROG1Selected
Push $R0

 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex} # Group 1 start
 
   SectionGetFlags 0 $R0            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R0 $R0 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R0 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R0 1
 
Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
 
Function IsPROG2Selected
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R1 ${PROG2_StartIndex}    # Group 2 start
 
   IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1
   SectionGetFlags 1 $R1            # Get section flags
    IntOp $R1 $R1 & ${SF_SELECTED}
    StrCmp $R1 ${SF_SELECTED} 0 +3      # If section is selected, done
     StrCpy $R1 1
 
Exch $R1
FunctionEnd

## Here we are selecting first sections to install
## by unselecting all the others!
Function SelectFilesA
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC1}
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #1 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
  ${Else}  
      Abort
  ${EndIf}  
 
 # If user clicks Back now, we will know to reselect Group 2`s sections for
 # Components page
 StrCpy $IfBack 1
 
 # We need to save the state of the Group 2 Sections
 # for the next InstFiles page
Push $R0
Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG2_StartIndex} # Group 2 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;   SectionGetFlags $R0 $R1                 # Get section flags
;    WriteINIStr "$PLUGINSDIR\sections.ini" Sections $R0 $R1 # Save state
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0               # Then unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG2_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
 # Don`t install prog 1?
 Call IsPROG1Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG1_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG1_InstDir}"
 
Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
 
## Here we need to unselect all Group 1 sections
## and then re-select those in Group 2 (that the user had selected on
## Components page)
Function SelectFilesB
  ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SEC3}
    ;MessageBox MB_OK "SEC1 #3 INSTDIR is $INSTDIR"
  ${Else}  
      Abort
  ${EndIf} 

Push $R0
;Push $R1
 
 StrCpy $R0 ${PROG1_StartIndex}    # Group 1 start
 
;  Loop:
;   IntOp $R0 $R0 + 1
;    !insertmacro UnselectSection $R0       # Unselect it
;    StrCmp $R0 ${PROG1_EndIndex} 0 Loop
 
; Call ResetFiles
 
 # Don't install prog 2?
 Call IsPROG2Selected
 Pop $R0
 StrCmp $R0 1 +4
  Pop $R1
  Pop $R0
  Abort
 
 # Set current $INSTDIR to PROG2_InstDir define
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "${PROG2_InstDir}"
 
;Pop $R1
Pop $R0
FunctionEnd
## Here we are deleting the temp INI file at the end of installation
Function DeleteSectionsINI
 FlushINI "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
 Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\Sections.ini"
 
  # FlexLM libs 
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "DeleteSectionsINI #1 MyAppInstallDir is $MyAppInstallDir"
  Delete $MyAppInstallDir\installs.exe
  Delete $MyAppInstallDir\lmborrow.exe
  
  # QI Pro files 
  ;MessageBox MB_OK "DeleteSectionsINI #1 FlexLmInstallDir is $FlexLmInstallDir"
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\config.dat
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\MyApp.exe
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\ReleaseNotes.txt
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\MyApp_LandingPage_114.bmp
  Delete $FlexLmInstallDir\MyAppLicense.txt
   
FunctionEnd
```